# Adenium Obesum swollen leaves and stem

Tags: houseplants

I am not sure what is wrong with my adenium plant. I have google exhaustively but couldn't find any description that my plant is facing. There seems to be some swelling at the leaves stem and on the leaves it self. If you take a look at the photo uploaded, you can see the swelling on the leaves stem (the connection from the leaves to the stem and also on the leaves. The swelling shows a bit red in color.
oh yes, currently my plant also have been infested by some bugs.
Hope someone can give me some solution here. This plant is about 18 years old.

thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Adenium has a scale/mealybug infestation; this can cause reddened swollen areas on leaves and stems. You can clean off any on the harder areas with 70% isopropyl alcohol and a cotton swab or a disposable cloth, but it won't get rid of the infestation completely. Seek out an insecticide that will treat for scale and spray with that - a particular insecticide is mentioned in this thread, but I don't know if that one is available in your area https://www.houzz.com/discussions/4856281/scale-insects-on-adenium-rose